# STEP II 1992: Line Bisectors and Axes of Hyperbola

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have been doing the problem given by[image]

and I managed to successfully get to the last part, however,  I am stuck. I am not certain as to how to find the equation of the line bisectors. My first thought was to just change the axies to be the two lines find the bisector and then translate it backwards but that seems to be too much effort as it says "deduce". And for the last part (I assume axes means directix) I suspect the axes are going to be the same as the bisectors but I do not understand why. If anybody could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please do not tag these sorts of problems as algebraic-geometry. From the tag description: "this tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry."

Comment: Also, please take the time to enter critical parts of your question as text instead of pasting a picture of it. This question is incomprehensible to someone who’s using a screen reader, which can’t read images. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last part, the slopes of the two asymptotes $y=3x-4$ and $3y=x-4$ are

$$ \tan a_1=3,\>\>\>\>\>\tan a_2= \frac13$$

which leads to $a_2= \frac\pi2-a_1$, i.e. the two asymptotes at the same angle with the $x$ and $y$ axes, respectively.

Then, by symmetry, the angle bisectors are at 45-degree angle with the axes, and the slopes are $\pm 1$. Given that the asymptotes $y=3x-4$ and $3y=x-4$ meet at $(1,-1)$, the equations of the bisectors are $y+1=\pm(x-1)$, or,

$$y=x-2,\>\>\>\>\>y=-x$$

which are also the equations of the axes of the hyperbola.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Could you possibly explain why are the angle bisectors at 45 degree angle with the x and y axis?

Comment: @KanyeWest - because the two asymptotes are at the same angle with the x and y axes respectively and the bisector is at the same angle with the two asymptotes, then, the bisector is at the same angle with the x and y axes, i.e. 45 degrees

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. That makes way more sense, thank you for taking the time to explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

The angle bisectors of a pair lines consist of all points that are equidistant from the lines. So, if you have the lines $ax+by+c=0$ and $px+qy+r=0$, use the standard point-line distance formula to construct the equation $${\lvert ax+by+c \rvert \over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = {\lvert px+qy+r \rvert \over \sqrt{p^2+q^2}}.$$ Removing the absolute value signs results in the two equations $${ax+by+c \over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = \pm{px+qy+r \over \sqrt{p^2+q^2}}$$ for the angle bisectors.

Plugging in the two equations from the question, we have, after rearranging and eliminating the common factor of $\sqrt{10}$, $$(3x-y-4)+(x-3y-4) = 4x-4y-8 = 0$$ and $$(3x-y-4)-(x-3y-4) = 2x+2y=0.$$ The slope of the first line is $1$ and that of the second $-1$. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will make sure to learn this approach, although I do not think this was what was required from the question as it said "deduce". Just a quick question. Is this formula derived from the approach I mentioned where one transforms the axis to be the lines and then finding the bisector and reverting it back?

Comment: @KanyeWest The way that I would deduce the slopes of the bisectors directly is by computing the bisectors of the normals to the two asymptotes, namely $(3,-1)\pm(1,3)$, and extracting slopes from those. Finding those normal bisectors is one small step away from having the equations of the angle bisector lines.

Comment: @KanyeWest The formula for the angle bisectors is derived, as I wrote in this answer, via a direct application of the point-line distance formula. That can be derived in various ways, including translating and rotating to a simple configuration, but it’s more usually derived by dropping a perpendicular from the point to the line or via projections.